# w3-include-html causing error in validation from https://validator.w3.org/

Tags: html, include, w3c-validation

I am using the w3 include for my footer on each page. The pages loads fine and everything works great except when I run the code through https://validator.w3.org/ for validation I am getting this error:

"Error: Attribute w3-include-html not allowed on element div at this point."

```
  <!--FOOTER-->
  <div w3-include-html="../includes/footer.html"></div>

  <!--Include HTML Files-->
  <script>
    w3.includeHTML();
  </script>
```

Is the w3 include not widely supported? Should I be doing this with PHP or asp.net? or ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using [a script offered by w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp). Note that w3schools has nothing to do with W3C. It’s just a custom JavaScript that makes use of an invalid attribute which likely gets replaced after the JS got executed.

The W3C HTML validator doesn’t execute JavaScript, so it doesn’t see the document after the JS replaced the attribute.

Possible solutions:

- If you want to validate your HTML after the JavaScript got executed, you could open your page in a browser, mark everything, open the source code for the selection, and copy-paste this markup into the W3C validator.
- If you just want to have a valid document before/without executing the JavaScript, you could change the script to use a [`data-*` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), e.g., `data-include-html`.
- If you want to support users and bots/services that don’t execute JavaScript, you shouldn’t rely on JavaScript. Using a server-side programming language (like PHP) could help here, but (depending on your use case) you could also just generate plain static HTML files, e.g., with the help of a [static site generator](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13636/60).